# Add MouseListener to JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing

I wrote this code for alert message shown to user when they uncheck the checkbox.  It only woks when I mouse key is realized with in the checkbox.  If user click the checkbox and release out of the  checkbox it allow user to uncheck the checkbox and doesn't shows alert message. How can I solve this bug?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {        
    Vector matNoVect = new Vector();
    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
        Utools.setMouseBusy(sstEndProductMaterials.table);
        try {   
            Vector v = new Vector();
            v = Inter.LoadContents(str);
            System.out.println(v);
            if (v.size() > 0) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(v.get(0).toString()) > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Material "+matNo+" is used in some Item");
                    sstEndProductMaterials.table.setValueAt(new Boolean(true),index, 7);
                    Utools.setMouseNormal(sstEndProductMaterials.table);
                    return;
                }
            }    
        } catch (Exception e11) {
            e11.printStackTrace();
            Utools.setMouseNormal(sstEndProductMaterials.table);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** Some users are NOT addicted to the mouse!  Which is why
it would be better to add an ActionListener to a JCheckBox. */
class CheckBoxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,20,20));

                JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox("Broken on keyboard");
                cb1.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                        System.out.println("Mouse click");
                    }
                } );
                p.add( cb1 );

                JCheckBox cb2 = new JCheckBox("Works for keyboard or mouse!");
                cb2.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        System.out.println("Event detected!");
                    }
                } );
                p.add( cb2 );

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good, cautionary example; possibly, one might prefer `ItemListener` over `ActionListener`. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Answer (score 3):

Use an ItemListener instead of a MouseListener

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox

You can then do this inside the ItemListener:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
        //Code to show alert etc.
    }
}
```